# Is Google running anonymous proxy servers?

Tags: proxy, google

I have discovered strange IP addresses in Apache logfiles:

```
74.125.78.95
74.125.38.82
```

For some users these IP addresses appear in the middle of the session.

What are these IP adresses? Is Google running proxy servers/anonymizers now?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it could be that they are identifying with something else than Googlebot as agent to check for cloaking based on user agent string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this link to project honeypot http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_74.125.78.95 It's just a webspider. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have 2 users who have logged in from Google's IP addresses 74.125.78.95 and 74.125.38.82. Is spider creating accounts?

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182072

Comment: If you look at the user agents listed on that page, you'll see that Google Wireless Transcoder (http://google.com/gwt/n) has been seen from that IP. That could explain why users have been logging in from it.